# How to scrape a table into R that requires a button pressed to view the table?

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

How do you to scrape a table where you need to click on tabs and buttons to view the table on the website.

These are the steps for just viewing the table at https://edudata.fldoe.org/ReportCards/Schools.html?school=0000&district=00:

1. Click 'Graduation and Beyond'
2. Click 'Postsecondary Continuation Rate'
3. Click 'Postsecondary Continuation Data Table Creation'
4. Click 'View Data'

---

R Version 3.6.2

I started using rvest_0.3.5

```
read_html("https://edudata.fldoe.org/ReportCards/Schools.html?school=0000&district=00")
node <- url %>% 
    html_nodes("div.my_container.margin_top_170") %>% 
    html_nodes("div.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12.mt-2") %>% 
    html_nodes("div") %>% 
    html_nodes("#accgrad")
node
[1] <div id="accgrad" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="gradhead" data-parent="#primaryaccordion"
```

I checked the HTML and the id, class, and parent matches where I want to be, but I can't go any further in my R-script for locating the table.

I also tried using xml2_1.2.2

```
theurl <- getURL("https://edudata.fldoe.org/ReportCards/Schools.html?school=0000&district=00")
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
tables
$`NULL`
   A  B  C  D  F
1               

$`NULL`
   A  B  C  D  F
1               

[[3]]
  TS&I CS&I
1
```

I did notice that there is a script in that looks like it is pulling the data, but I don't have enough html knowledge to be sure.

```
<script> $("#accgrad").load("accordions/acc_graduation.html");</script>
```

It looks like the table is located in:

```
<table id="tablePostsecenroll" class="display no-footer dataTable dtr-inline" 
style="width:100%;" role="grid" aria-describedby="tablePostsecenroll_info">
```

Once I have access to the table, I will want to read it into a data.frame. But I can probably figure that out once I have access to the html text of the table.

Thank you for taking the time to work on this problem!

Answer (score 1):

The data is not on the page source. It is generated by javascript. So, `rvest` can not be used to scrape the data table directly.

One of some approaches is using `XHR`: find request URL that return your data (open Chrome or Firefox developer tools, go to the Network tab, load your page/data, and find appropriate request). Once you find it, make your scraper send requests to this URL.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it was exactly what I was missing. I would upvote this, except I don't have enough reputation to do so.
If someone else sees it, please upvote nurandi's answer.

For additional information on the request URL, I used this post:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference

Comment: You should be able to mark the answer as correct, even if you can't upvote.